# VSCode origin script issues with yarn

Tags: python, node.js, visual-studio-code, npm

I am trying to install the open source code of vscode on my local machine, following the official website. So, i forked on my github, i cloned the repo locally, I installed Yarn, and then I entered the repo with simply `cd vscode`.

Then, I should use the command `yarn`, and everything should be installed and ready to run. But the following error occurs, and I as a beginner of open source, am struggling fixing it

```
[1/18] ⠈ @parcel/watcher
[6/18] ⠈ native-keymap
[3/18] ⠈ @vscode/sqlite3
[4/18] ⠈ keytar
error C:\Users\mposs\OneDrive\Desktop\Files\open_source\vscode\node_modules\native-is-elevated: Command failed.
Exit code: 7
Command: node-gyp rebuild
Arguments:
Directory: C:\Users\mposs\OneDrive\Desktop\Files\open_source\vscode\node_modules\native-is-elevated
Output:
C:\Users\mposs\OneDrive\Desktop\Files\open_source\vscode\node_modules\native-is-elevated>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
gyp info using node@16.14.0 | win32 | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.1 found at "C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe"
gyp info find VS using VS2022 (17.2.32505.173) found at:
gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"
gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
gyp info spawn C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\mposs\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Files\\open_source\\vscode\\node_modules\\native-is-elevated\\build\\config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\mposs\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\17.4.3\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\mposs\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\17.4.3',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\mposs\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\17.4.3\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\mposs\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Files\\open_source\\vscode\\node_modules\\native-is-elevated',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\mposs\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Files\\open_source\\vscode\\node_modules\\native-is-elevated\\build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION
gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe ENOENT
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22000
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\mposs\OneDrive\Desktop\Files\open_source\vscode\node_modules\native-is-elevated
gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.0
```

I can't understand why this problem is occurring. I tryied deleting everything, and restart, but it didn't worked.

I just started using it, please help me

Comment: "gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION" Unable to judge